# VXML Form, passing values to PHP and back

Tags: php, forms, vxml

I have a very basic dial form that detects DTMF and then submits this to dial.php

As the form is submitted the digits are passed and I can GET them using `$_GET['digits']`

This works well.  But if I don't submit the form, just use `<goto next="#dial">` how can I retrieve the digits and assign them to a value so I can use PHP to do a look up ?

Also if an invalid number is entered I can throw an event and then use catch to route it back to the original form. How ever when that form is submitted the event count is lost. Is there any way to have that persist when the form is submitted ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In VXML the ***goto*** is generally used to navigate within a document. You can call an external document (which could be your PHP) but it does not have a ***namelist*** attribute to pass information in the query string. You could build the query string into the URI but you cannot do it dynamically because the ***next*** attribute does not accept expressions.

The best way to pass information to a PHP application is to use the ***submit*** or ***subdialog*** tags, which both have ***namelist*** attributes for passing data. The ***subdialog*** is used to called reusable common dialogs and will return back to where execution left off in the calling document. And it can return data back to the calling document.  Whereas the ***submit*** does not return automatically to the calling document.

If you want information to persist (without persisting it in the backend) you use the root document to assign variables.  Variable in the root document are global to the whole application and will persist throughout the call. You can read more about the root document in the [VoiceXML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/), section 1.3.3.

Comment: Many thanks :) If I use persistent variables, can there value be passed to PHP, or can that only be done with a submit ?

Comment: I am assuming by the way you phrased the question that you are actually asking, "Can global variables in the root document be passed to a PHP application by using a goto statement?"  I say maybe because the  vxml specification does not really talk about this, so it may be platform dependent. It may be that IVR (VoicXML Browser) passes these global variables around in the query string so it does not have to maintain state. Check the raw URI being sent to your PHP application to see if this is true for your IVR platform.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches to solve this problem.  As you mentioned if you leave the current page all of your built-in error counters are reset.  One solution is to make use of a common root document which can store "global" variables that will persist across page transitions.  You will need to manually handle all of the error counting on your own by manipulating these application level variables.  The second, more elegant solution is to use a  tag which allow you to send data to another script which can choose to execute more VoiceXML and then return back to the current script without losing context.  Subdialogs can be thought of much like a function call.  Your current scope is preserved and a new scope is created.  You can pass in variables and get return values.  Here is a contrived example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version="2.1">
  <form id="getdigits">
    <field name="digits" type="digits">
      <prompt>Please enter some digits</prompt>
    </field>
    <subdialog name="dial" src="dial.php" namelist="" method="get">
      <filled>
        <if cond="dial.status == 'failure'">
          <goto next="#getdigits"/>
        </if>
        <goto next="someotherpage.php"/>
      </filled>
    </subdialog>
  </form>
</vxml>

<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
$status = $_GET['digits'] == '1234' ? 'success' : 'failure';
?>
<vxml version="2.1">
  <form>
    <block>
      <var name="status" expr="'<?=$status?>'"/>
      <return namelist="status"/>
    </block>
  </form>
</vxml>
```